# How to manage on startup ports and services

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, openssh, tor

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and I downloaded some applications/services like Apache server, MySQL, tor-socks and OpenSSH server.

The problem is the ports associated with those services are opened when I turn on my device.

How can I make them turned off by default on startup (without deleting them)?

For now I did a quick solution, I added an alias command that turns them off to the `.bashrc` file, which is:
`alias killports='sudo pkill ssh;sudo service tor stop;sudo service mysql stop;sudo pkill apache2;'`

But in this case I have to type the `killports` command every time when I turn my device on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services can be disabled using systemd. This is especially useful if you are running a non-graphical version of Ubuntu. In a terminal, run

```
sudo systemctl disable service_name
```

where `service_name` is the name of a service (`sshd`, `apache2`, etc). This prevents them from running on startup. To list the available services, use

```
systemctl -t service list-units
```

This command gives information about services on your machine:

- The service name, including `.service`, which isn't necessary for the commands (you can run the commands with `mysql` or `mysql.service`)
- Whether the service was loaded correctly
- Whether the service is currently active (can be run)
- Whether the service is currently running
- A brief description of the service

If you'd like to start or start a service manually, use

```
sudo systemctl start service_name
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop service_name
```

Services can be enabled to run at startup again using

```
sudo systemctl enable service_name
```

This eliminates the necessity for you to type a command every time at startup.

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu 18.04 installs the utility [*Startup Applications*](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en).

- You can open this from the command line.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> [or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>] to open *Terminal*
- Type

  ```
  gnome-session-properties
  ```

  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- An alternative way to open the utility is to press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key [AKA <kbd>Windows</kbd> key].
- Type `startu`.
- Select [*Startup Applications*](https://websiteforstudents.com/set-apps-to-auto-startup-at-logon-on-ubuntu-17-10-18-04/).

**N.B.** [Some applications are hidden](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications) from that utility for safety, but can be shown. Open *Terminal*, as above, and enter:

```
 sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Be cautious about disabling some startups, which might be essential to the OS or GUI.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem now that I can't determine which startup is associated to which service